# How can i change the version of ivy sbt is using

Tags: sbt

I think I have ran into a bug in ivy, that may have ben solved in version 2.4.0-rc1 of ivy.

But how can i see what version of ivy sbt is using, and how can i change it to 2.4.0-rc1, so i can test if it actually fixes my problem.

Comment: sbt use ivy in version mentioned in: https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/0.13/project/Util.scala#L181 I think you can override it in your local repository.